# Project Tasks seem to take longer than entered

Tags: project-management, microsoft-project

In Microsoft Project 2007, I can't work out why my tasks are scheduled to finish later than I would expect for the Duration I put in.

I enter a task with a start date on a Monday and a 1-day duration, and it shows the Finish as Tuesday.

```
Task Name     Duration  Start       Finish
Do Something     1 day  12/04/2010  13/04/2010
```

How can I set this up so a one-day task takes one day, and not one-and-a-bit?  I want a one-day task that starts on a Monday to finish on the Monday.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, I found it.

In `Change Working Time`, the working day in the `Work Weeks` tab details was defined as being 0900-1200 and 1400-1700, so that's only 6 working hours a day, but the `Options` had the setting `Hours per day` set to 8 hours.

That meant a task entered for `1 day`, which equals 8 hours, clearly can't fit in on 'real' 6-hour day.